# Connect to separate geth with Ethereum Wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am fed up with the slow syncing progress of the Ethereum Wallet from ethereum.org. Every time I start it up I have to wait.

It would be much more convenient to have a geth instance running remotely and connect it to the Ethereum Wallet.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have some serious security implications. However, you can use a transaction signer: [Metamask](https://metamask.io). Widely used Browser Plugin for Chrome, which holds keys locally on your computer, signs transactions for you and sends them to a always synced node to be transacted to the network. 
Have Fun.

Comment: Yeah I am doing that and it works quite ok. I was hoping this was also possible in the Ethereum Wallet. I guess the desktop client of Ethereum Wallet becomes somewhat obsolete as they created a web version as well at wallet.ethereum.org

Comment: You can, indeed, connect to a remote node, via the so called RPC feature, but that's not safe per se, as there is ne SSL by default when doing that. Also, use metamask instead of web wallets, theey tend to get hacked.. ;)

Comment: https://wallet.ethereum.org only lives in the browser (no calls to backend) as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am mistaken, wallet.ethereum.org actually also requires Metamask to inject the private key into js.